# How to overlay a linegraph over a stacked bar plot (Dplyr)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, stacked-chart, linegraph

I am creating a stacked bar plot showing the change in party preference of a sample over the years. Although that part is done, I want to plot a line graph over the bar graph looking at percentage of the sample that has changed from the previous year.

I've currently plotted two separate stacked bar graphs but think they'd look better fused into one.

My data looks like this:

```
ID   Year   Party  Change
1    2010   Labour  NA
1    2011   Labour  No Change
1    2012   Con     Change
1    2013   Con     No Change
2    2010   Con     No Change
2    2011   Con     No Change
2    2012   Con     No Change
2    2013   Con     No Change
... etc.
```

These are the graphs I've already plotted.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(Change) %>%
  filter(Year != 2010) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Change, y = ID, x= Year)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("% of Sample")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ipw.jpg

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill = PolParty, y = pidp, x = wave)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("% of Sample") +
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVJNL.jpg

I would ideally like to overlay the first graph over the 2nd in the form of a line graph. The axis are the same so I don't think that would be a problem, but I don't know how to transform the stacked bar graph into a line graph.

Comment: Where does the `wave` variable come from? Is it different from the other x-axis, `YEar`?

Comment: Wave is year, I apologise for that. I thought it would be clearer to say year since that's what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the full dataset, we'd get an answer that would more accurately reflect the question; but as a quick and dirty solution, you'd want to use something like the code below.

I've altered the names to make a bit clearer what's going on. I'm assuming that `df` actually has all the variables you mentioned. Probably best to wrangle the relevant variables into two separate dataframes and then pass them to each `geom_` separately.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- "ID   Year   Party  Changed_seats
1    2010   Labour  NA
1    2011   Labour  No_Change
1    2012   Con     Change
1    2013   Con     No_Change
2    2010   Con     No_Change
2    2011   Con     No_Change
2    2012   Con     No_Change
2    2013   Con     No_Change
3    2014   Con     No_Change
3    2015   Con     Change
3    2016   Con     Change
3    2017   Con     No_Change
4    2014   Con     No_Change
4    2015   Con     Change
4    2016   Con     Change
4    2017   Con     No_Change"

df <- read.table(text = data, header = TRUE) 


seat_changes_df <- df %>%
  select(Year, Changed_seats) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.factor(Year)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(Prop_change = sum(Changed_seats == "Change")/n())

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = seat_changes_df, aes(x = Year, y = Prop_change), group = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Seats changed")
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredible. I feel like this should work but for some reason my console automatically "adds missing grouping variables: `id`". How can I disable this? The output currently just plots a horizontal line.

Comment: At some point before you've put `id` into a `group_by` call, either by name (which should be obvious) or by position (`group_by(1:3)`, i.e. more insidious). You may need to `ungroup()` before further operations or reconsider the need for grouping by `id`.